# Determining which JavaScript/CSS browser features are required

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-detection

My website uses a variety of technologies, such as JQuery, new CSS definitions (e.g., moz-selection, -webkit-user-select), etc.

The site works perfectly with Google Chrome and Safari, but has some quirkiness in Firefox, IE, and some of the other browsers.

I want to write a script to check for necessary browser features but, with several thousand lines of code and CSS definitions, I'm not certain which features I should be looking for.

Is there some sort of online analysis (similar to how JSLint operates) that would tell me which features my script and CSS files need? Are there tools (like FireBug) that provide this info?

Comment: Perhaps [Common feature tests](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/cft/) and links therein are useful (to check which browser supports which features). An automated file search is the other thing I can think of (I don't know any parser like that).

Comment: It should be noted that moz-selection and webkit-user-selection aren't standard, so if you're using them, thats why you're not getting consistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: Marcel: Thank you for your answer. It sure would be great if there was a parser for that.

Comment: Itz: Thank you also. So far, the style differences have been minor. I have stranger problems. For instance, I let users upload photos that appear inside as img frames inside of a div. They can then navigate to another div, which I animate via JQuery slide. It works fine for most browsers, including those I didn't mention above, but in Firefox, when the user returns/animates back to the div, the img frames are empty. If s/he goes away and comes back a second time, the images are completely hidden. In other browsers, the image appearance persists, as it should.

Comment: Alan, use an at-sign before a user name to notify him, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: Just read your message to Itz. I think you should file another question for that problem, preferably with an example page. Just some suggestions: when the img frames are empty, do you see them in the DOM (e.g. in Firebug)? And if so, what are the CSS styles?

Comment: @Marcel: Thank you for note about addressing people. The image problem is a bit complex and I realize that I described it incorrectly. I allow users to upload photos which then appear as background-images in a table cells. In FF, hiding and re-displaying the parent DIV (via slide effect) causes the TD definition to be scrambled (based on what I see in Firebug). In Chrome and Safari, the TD definition is preserved as it should be. You're right, though, this deserves a new posting. First, I need to double-check my code to make sure I'm not blowing something that Chrome is forgiving and FF isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ull ever find that fabulous script.
As an alternative [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [IE7 JS](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com) will probably satisfy most of your needs for now.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had never heard of Modernizr.